# Find the solution to a system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

Initially I'd like to solve the following problem:

> Find $x$: $$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}$$

I'm already aware of one approach to solve it, but now I wonder what if I set $y=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}$
?

That is, to solve the following system:
$$ \begin{cases} x = \sqrt{ 2+ \sqrt{ 2+y }} \\ y= \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}  \end{cases}$$

Comment: It looks like this problem reduces to finding the $x$ to the original problem and then setting $y := \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + x}}$, as $y$ is completely specified by $x$ (choice of root notwithstanding).

Comment: @user2628206 if $x=y$ it'll be really eazy, and yet I can't find a way to prove it

Comment: I don't think that setting $y  := x$ is helpful here. You say you have one solution to $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}$, observe by substituting the second equation in the system into the first that any solution $(x,y)$ must have $x$ a solution to the original problem - do you need help finding other solutions to the original problem too?

Comment: @user2628206 Well, I mean I have already found a way to solve the equation, but not have found an $x$ that makes the equation work. There is obviously only one solution to the equation, that is, $x=2$, and what I want to do is use substiution to solve it.

Comment: Ah!, I see now you are asking about method and not just finding the appropriate (x,y): see the given answer for that! If you are just considering the principle root then there is only one solution. Otherwise, if considering branches of the square root also then there may be other solutions - but that is a topic adjacent to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're basically hoping to see some "systems of equations"-specific method that solves the system you gave. Unfortunately, methods for solving the system are mostly going to come down to a) solve one of the equations for one of the variables, b) plug that into the other equation and solve from there. In this case, that just gives
$$x = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+y}} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}$$
...which is your original equation again. That's probably the easiest way to solve this system of equations, but that takes the fun out of it since the whole point was to avoid the standard method of solving the original equation.

If you really want to work with the system and not with the original equation, you could try numerical methods like [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) using a computer. These methods would basically let you choose a starting guess $(x_0, y_0)$ and then iterate to get closer to the solution (or sometimes they don't converge depending on the quality of your starting guess). It wouldn't give you an exact formula for the answer though, just a list of decimal numbers that get very close to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this makes sense since now you have two unknowns and two equations. For your system, all you need to do is just find the relationship between $x$ and $y$ and plug in, then finally you have to solve an equation which is $$\big[[(x^2-2)^2-2]^2-2\big]^2-2=x$$.

However, this doesn't seem so convenient. You can also set $$y:= \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}$$
This also won't be a convenient idea, since it will finally bring you to solve the equation above.

Thus seemingly your method can't easily solve the problem here.

I guess you already know that you can change the original problem into a recursive sequence. If your method isn't this one. I introduce it. And this method is pretty widely used in dealing with this kind of problem.

$$ x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}$$

This is $$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}}$$

We set
$$\begin{aligned} & a_1= \sqrt{2} \\ & a_2={\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} \\  & a_3=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\\  & \vdots \end{aligned} $$

This is $$\begin{aligned} & a_1= \sqrt{2} \\ & a_2={\sqrt{2+a_1}} \\ & a_3=\sqrt{2+a_2} \\ &\vdots \end{aligned} $$

The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is increasing (clear) and bounded above (bounded by 2 you can verify by induction). Thus it has limit, suppose it's limit is $a$, we have $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}\iff a = \sqrt{2+a} \implies a=2,-1$$

It's clear that $a>0$, so $a=2$ which is $x$

Comment: Very nice method. I prove that the solution to $x=\sqrt{2+x}$ must be a solution to the original one, and then I prove its uniqueness, which is quite similar to your method.

Answer (score 1):

I've just got an idea.

Let's suppose $x>y$, then $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+y}}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}=y$, which is impossible. When $x<y$ it's the same. Hence $x=y$.

As a result, $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2+x}\Rightarrow x^2=2+\sqrt{2+x}\Rightarrow x^4-4x^2+4=x+2\Rightarrow x^4-4x^2-x+2=0\Rightarrow$$\left(x^2+x-1\right)\left(x+1\right)\left(x-2\right)=0\Rightarrow x=2$.

If there's any mistake please tell me.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%3Dsqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bx%29%29%29%29

Comment: @BobDobbs Thanks but I'm fully aware of the answer. I'm confirming if the process is correct.

Comment: What is $y$? @Thomas

Comment: @BobDobbs See the question, please.

Comment: I checked the inequalities. It seems correct to me to deduce that $x=y>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Render $x=2\cos\theta$. Prove that if $f(\theta)=2\cos(\theta)$ then

$f(\theta/2)=\sqrt{2+f(\theta)}.$

Thereby prove that

$\cos(\theta)=\cos(\theta/16)$

and solve this equation by exploiting the periodicity and symmetry of the cosine function.

You should get sixteen distinct values of $x$. Only four of these are actually equal to $y$ in your system of equations.